# WP7 Reminder issue when application is focused

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a reminder notification which passes a parameter to my app like this

```
Reminder closeReminder = new Reminder(somevalue);
closeReminder.BeginTime = testtime;
closeReminder.Content = "Tap here!";
closeReminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
closeReminder.NavigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?para=paraone", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
closeReminder.Title = "Title here";
```

My problem is, If the application is already opened and reminder pop-up, when i tap on the notification nothing happens. It does not call `OnNavigatedTo` in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` even. If the application is not focused, no issues. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue, it's by design. From [Peter Torr's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/05/28/alarms-and-notifications-in-mango.aspx):

> Note that if your app is currently in the foreground when the reminder
>   is fired, tapping on the title / content will dismiss the reminder but
>   will not cause a navigation (since your app is already running).

Answer (score 2):

Like KeyboardP states this is by design. Reminders are a way of getting a user to your application at a certain time, there's no point in doing that when they are already in. Your are expected to take care of this yourself since your app should be aware of the reason the reminder is fired anyway.